# Can a Hamburger button be good as a backup?

Tags: navigation, hamburger

I read *many* answers here that the Hamburger button is bad as many people don't look there and don't end up using all the app's power.

However, can one use it as an index *in addition* to normal full page navigation?

Comment: Most research shows that people don't voluntarily engage with a hamburger menu as much as an icon bar. But that doesn't mean people don't use hamburger menus.

Comment: Why would you want it in addition? If you have the primary - why add clutter with the hamburger icon?

Comment: @Mayo it's faster. Like Amazon's Shop by department

Comment: You're doing things backwards. Don't come up with an interesting solution and then try to find a problem to apply it to; figure out what the problem is first and then research a solution. Your hamburger-on-desktop idea is a solution in search of a problem. What real (not hypothetical) problem in your system does it solve?

Comment: @JonW Not a desktop, an Android App

Answer (score 3):

**Pick one of the two options. Don't make a second menu that's exactly the same.**  People will be confused or annoyed if they discover the same menu after spending a mouse click on a hamburger menu.

So which one to choose?

**In apps**

Don't use a full page navigation, because mobile screens are small. A hamburger menu will do fine, because people can see it easily. I think people are getting used to the hamburger menu now, after [25 years](http://blog.placeit.net/history-of-the-hamburger-icon/). It's everywhere now.

**Desktop / laptops**

This is the place where hamburger menus are hard to see because they are small in comparison to the average monitor size.

### Alternative for the hamburger menu

This is an interesting A/B test, which concludes that the word "menu" with a border around it will work better than the hamburger menu: http://exisweb.net/mobile-menu-abtest It's something you could consider if your target audience isn't fully aware of the function of a hamburger menu (like the elderly).